# Vue live update props array in axios callback

Tags: javascript, vue.js

this time its something general and simple so i have not really code to provide.
The general steps are:

- Pass an array as a prop to a child component
- Inside the child component loop over the array with v-for
- now i call an axios post method to modify the "user-list" (the user list is the array)
  vue should now update this array but it doesnt because a prop is not reactive.
  The Main question is: How do i use computed properties as passed down props to have the array live updated?

here is some code though:

```
       <div class="users" v-for="participant in part" :key="participant.id">
          <template v-if="participant.name !== username">
            {{participant.name}}
            <span>
              <a style="cursor:pointer" title="kick" @click="kickUser(participant)">
```

...

```
  props: ["participants", "username", "channel"],

  methods: {
kickUser(user) {
  axios
    .post("/kickuser", { user: user, channel: this.channel })
    // .then((this.participants = []));
}
```

the kickuser axios post method removes a user from the db so the array is reduced by the user kicked
hope you can help me with the computed properties

Comment: See [One-Way Data Flow](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow). Your child component should emit an event to the parent which should then update the array

Comment: so if i emit that event and modify the prop that gets sent down it changes? ill test it out in the morning, please post as answer so i can accept if it works

Comment: _"now i call an axios post method"_  where? In which component? _"prop is not reactive"_  they certainly are reactive. _"How do i use computed properties as passed down props"_  what _computed property_? I would not have these questions if you provided a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: its fine actually your comment sufficed. but to answer your questions : axios method is in kickuser function in child component , all code provided is from the child component, the parent component just passes down the array. i thought about using computed properties for some reason because i read somewhere that props arent reactive. sry for confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions here so I'll probably need to edit this as information comes to light...

You have a parent component with data. For example

```js
data: () => ({ participants: [...] }),
```

You then pass that data to a child component

```html
<Child :participants="participants" 
       :username="..." :channel="..."/>
```

and within that child component, you perform an action that involves making an HTTP request.

---

What you do then is emit an event from the child component

```js
methods: {
  async kickUser (user) {
    let { data } = await axios.post('/kickuser', { user, channel: this.channel })
    this.$emit('kick', data)
  }
}
```

and listen for this event in the parent

```html
<Child :participants="participants" @kick="handleKick"
       :username="..." :channel="..."/>
```

```js
// parent "methods"
methods: {
  handleKick (data) {
    this.participants = [] // or whatever you need to do
  }
}
```

This process is outlined in Vue's documentation ~ [One-Way Data Flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)